# What is the purpose of "input.length();"?

Tags: c++

I am taking a college level C++ course, and quite frankly nothing is really ever explained.  I was given code to write, and my program works as it should. I would just like to know the purpose of certain lines.

Such as:

```
int i = 0;
```

I know I am declaring an `int` variable that = 0. Here my question is why the letter `i`? Could that be any variable name I choose?

```
int length = input.length();
```

I know I am declaring an `int` variable named `length`... but what purpose does it serve in my code?

```
i++
```

I think this ends my loop?

I have added my code for perusal. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Program takes user entered letter and matches it with the corresponding ICAO word.
//Program has been modified to use void and string methods

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

//Function Heading
void convert(string);

//Main Function
int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << " Enter a letter or word: ";   // Ask the user to enter a letter or word.
    cin >> input;                          //get input
    cout << "Phonetic Version : ";         //Display "Phonetic Version"

    convert (input);                        
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}//End Main

//Function Definition
void convert(string input)
{
    int i = 0;      //input variable
    char letters;   //character variable 
    int length = input.length(); 

    while (i < length)      //While loop initialized
    {
        letters = input.at(i);
        if (letters == 'a' || letters == 'A')
            cout << "Alpha ";
        else if (letters == 'b' || letters == 'B')
            cout << "Bravo ";
        else if (letters == 'c' || letters == 'C')
            cout << "Charlie ";
        else if (letters == 'd' || letters == 'D')
            cout << "Delta ";
        else if (letters == 'e' || letters == 'E')
            cout << "Echo ";
        else if (letters == 'f' || letters == 'F')
            cout << "Foxtrot ";
        else if (letters == 'g' || letters == 'G')
            cout << "Golf ";
        else if (letters == 'h' || letters == 'H')
            cout << "Hotel ";
        else if (letters == 'i' || letters == 'I')
            cout << "India ";
        else if (letters == 'j' || letters == 'J')
            cout << "Juliet ";
        else if (letters == 'k' || letters == 'K')
            cout << "Kilo ";
        else if (letters == 'l' || letters == 'L')
            cout << "Lima ";
        else if (letters == 'm' || letters == 'M')
            cout << "Mike ";
        else if (letters == 'n' || letters == 'N')
            cout << "November ";
        else if (letters == 'o' || letters == 'O')
            cout << "Oscar ";
        else if (letters == 'p' || letters == 'P')
            cout << "Papa ";
        else if (letters == 'q' || letters == 'Q')
            cout << "Quebec ";
        else if (letters == 'r' || letters == 'R')
            cout << "Romeo ";
        else if (letters == 's' || letters == 'S')
            cout << "Sierra ";
        else if (letters == 't' || letters == 'T')
            cout << "Tango ";
        else if (letters == 'u' || letters == 'U')
            cout << "Uniform ";
        else if (letters == 'v' || letters == 'V')
            cout << "Victor ";
        else if (letters == 'w' || letters == 'W')
            cout << "Whiskey ";
        else if (letters == 'x' || letters == 'X')
            cout << "X-ray ";
        else if (letters == 'y' || letters == 'Y')
            cout << "Yankee ";
        else if (letters == 'z' || letters == 'Z')
            cout << "Zulu ";
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"what purpose does it serve in my code?"* - if it's *your* code, what purpose did you have in mind when you wrote it ?

Comment: You must read how to name variables, there are certain rules. Your second question is, assume you have a string variable called `input`. You are assigning its number of characters to `length`.

Comment: Perhaps I should say "What purpose does it serve in THIS code?" I wrote the code but was advised by the professor to use this variable block between the void and while loop. There was no detail into why this line exists in my book, when asked in class my answer was"Because this is what we do for this code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> int length = input.length();
> ```
>
> I know I am declaring an int variable named length... but what purpose
>   does it serve in my code?

None.

It would serve some purpose if `input`'s length would change later on and you'd need to remember the old length for some reason.

Since this is not the case here, your professor may think that this is some kind of "optimisation" on the grounds that repeatedly calling `length()` may be too slow. But this is nonsense; your computer is too fast for such micro-optimisations to have an observable effect, especially with modern compilers being much better at optimising programs than the programmers themselves.

Just remove the `length` variable to make the code shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
string input;
```

`std::string` has a method called [length()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) which returns the length of the string, in terms of bytes. Hence you are using like

```
int length = input.length(); /* use variable name as other than predefined method to avoid confusion */
     |               |
 this is just       this is a method of string
 a int variable
```

Comment: As always, it's a bad idea to use cplusplus.com as a reference. While it is correct that `length` returns the number of bytes in the case of `std::string`, this is not generally true for `std::basic_string`. Here's a better reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHackl I'll keep this thing in mind for my reference.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int i = 0;
> ```
>
> I know I am declaring an `int` variable that = 0. Here my question is why the letter `i`? Could that be any variable name I choose?

Yes. Variable names are arbitrary, name them however you want (within the restrictions of the language syntax, of course). Just make sure you use names that are meaningful within the context in which they are being used.  Readability matters when maintaining code over time.

> ```
> int length = input.length();
> ```
>
> I know I am declaring an `int` variable named `length`... but what purpose does it serve in my code?

To make a local cached copy of the character count of the `input` string so your loop does not have to keep calling the string's `length()` method over and over. Using a few bytes of local stack space can save time and overhead of retrieving the string's length, which does not change while the loop runs.

> ```
> i++
> ```
>
> I think this ends my loop?

It increments the value of the `i` variable, nothing more. The loop ends when the `while` statement evaluates as false (when `i` catches up to `length`).

Comment: Thank you so much! It infuriates me when professors give the "Because it is what we do. It just is..."  answer. This helps immensely!